# How to access files from root folder

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file inside a folder structure a bit like this:

./JS/main.js

and i want to access a folder that is located here:

./img/img1.png

How would I be able to locate this image?

Comment: It might depend on how you are accessing this file. For example, if your JavaScript file is dynamically creating an img tag with that as it's "src", then the supplied URL would need to be relative to your HTML document. Other forms of fetching the file may require a URL that's relative to something else, like your JavaScript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using plain old js, then you can "go back a folder" with `..`

In this case, it would be: `../../img/img1.png`.

Otherwise, you should check out your framework's documentation on loading assets!